# Pandas dataframe - add suffix to column value only if it is repeated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a column in a data frame which looks like -

| Key |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| A |
| A |

I want to transform this so that each key has a suffix "_" + "order of occurrence if value is repeated" i.e. to look like  -

| Key |
| --- |
| A_1 |
| B |
| C |
| A_2 |
| A_3 |

Reading related threads I understand it would have to be a play on groupby and cumcount but cant seem to get the final solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try with `cumcount` then `mask` with total `count` for each group

```
g = df.groupby('Key')
df['Key'] += g.cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('_').mask(g['Key'].transform('count')==1,'')
df
   Key
0  A_1
1    B
2    C
3  A_2
4  A_3
```

Comment: Nice, but missing this line? `g = df.groupby('Key')`

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d5880566321a> in <module>
----> 1 df['Key'] += g.cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('_').mask(g['Key'].transform('count')==1,'')

NameError: name 'g' is not defined