# dd prefix to duplicate values AND add new rows with this values to a certain groups in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df  such as

```
Type   Species     Value
Dog    Species2    100
Dog    Species1    200
Dog    Species3    300
Dog    Species3    900
ALL_   Species1    400
ALL_   Species2    500
ALL_   Species3    600
```

how can I add rows to `ALL_` for each duplicated Species while also adding a `suffix_number` to the duplicated Species in `ALL_` and `DOG`

I should then get :

```
Type   Species     Value
Dog    Species2    100
Dog    Species1    200
Dog    Species3_1  300
Dog    Species3_2  900
ALL_   Species1    400
ALL_   Species2    500
ALL_   Species3_1  600
ALL_   Species3_2  600
```

This is not a duplicate of [Pandas dataframe - add suffix to column value only if it is repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914097/pandas-dataframe-add-suffix-to-column-value-only-if-it-is-repeated) since I also need to add new rows for duplicated Species only in groups `ALL_`

Here is the dataframe if it can helps :

```
data = {'Type': ['Mammuthus', 'Mammuthus', 'Mammuthus', 'Mammuthus', 'ALL_', 'ALL_', 'ALL_'],
        'Species': ['Species2', 'Species1', 'Species3', 'Species3', 'Species1', 'Species2', 'Species3'],
        'Value': [100, 200, 300, 900, 400, 500, 600]}
```

Comment: Is `ALL_   Species3_2  600` in the desired output an error? I don't see Species_3 duplicated in the provided input example so just want to confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### filling missing combinations

```
out = (df
   .assign(idx=df.groupby(['Type', 'Species']).cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index=['Species', 'idx'], columns='Type', values='Value')
   .groupby(level='Species').ffill()
   .reset_index().melt(['Species', 'idx'])
   .assign(Species=lambda d: d['Species'] + ('_'+d.pop('idx').astype(str))
                   .where(d.duplicated(['Species', 'Type'], keep=False), ''))
 )
```

Output:

```
      Species       Type  value
0    Species1       ALL_  400.0
1    Species2       ALL_  500.0
2  Species3_1       ALL_  600.0
3  Species3_2       ALL_  600.0
4    Species1  Mammuthus  200.0
5    Species2  Mammuthus  100.0
6  Species3_1  Mammuthus  300.0
7  Species3_2  Mammuthus  900.0
```

##### original answer

You can use a custom [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) per group:

```
df['Species'] += (df.groupby('Type')['Species']
                    .transform(lambda s: s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1)
                                          .astype(str).radd('_')
                                          .where(s.duplicated(keep=False), '')
                              )
                 )
```

Alternative syntax:

```
m = df.duplicated(subset=['Type', 'Species'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'Species'] += (m[m].groupby([df['Type'], df['Species']])
                         .cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('_')
                        )
```

Output:

```
   Type     Species  Value
0   Dog    Species2    100
1   Dog    Species1    200
2   Dog  Species3_1    300
3   Dog  Species3_2    900
4  ALL_    Species1    400
5  ALL_    Species2    500
6  ALL_    Species3    600
```

Comment: Hello thanks but I should add two rows in ALL_ Species3_1 and Species3_2 because there were 2 duplicates in Dog

Comment: @Grendel OK got it, but honestly this is poorly explained, you should make the question more clear. I thought this was a typo

Comment: @Grendel See update